# Is there any way to make edges corners become rounded?

Tags: modeling, mesh, scale

i'm a new blender i'm trying to making edges corners become rounded but i couldn't find any way to makes it.I tried to use Insert faces (shortcut I)
and Bevel but it didn't work as i expected,i don't know if i have missed something please give me an advice.

1.As you can see at first picture the red circles where i want it to be rounded
2.I want my corners to be rounded as second picture at red circles
[image: As you can see the red circles where i want it to be rounded]

[image: Finally here! i want my corners to be curves as this picture at red circles]

[image]

Comment: try Ctrl+Shift+B

Comment: probably you should say round instead of curve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rounding the corners of the inset face cannot be done directly.

But you can extrude it and so have a "volume" that can be beveled.

[image]

- Select the inset face
- Extrude <kbd>E</kbd>
- Go to edge select mode <kbd>Ctr</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Select the edges
- Bevel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (use mouse wheel or +/- from the numpad to choose the amount of bevel)
- Once ok, remove the extrude face (select it then <kbd>X</kbd> then vertices)
- Remake the original face: back to edge select mode <kbd>Ctr</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd> select the border then <kbd>F</kbd> to make the face

Comment: Hi lemon This is exactly what i'm looking for.Thank you so much you saved me.I actually moved from 3dsmax/maya i've just found blender this is very amazing software it's free and open source so powerful and can do entire things as 3ds max thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two bevel functions.

1. Normal Egde Bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
2. Vertex Bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

What you want to do is bevel/round the corners/vertices.

Comment: I did as you said but it's still not be as i expected.Anyway thank you for correcting me this my very first time blender