# Bevel concave corner

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel

I am trying to bevel an object like this:

[image]

However, when I hit CTRL+SHIFT+B to bevel, the following happens instead.

[image]

The convex corners bevel as expected, but the convex corners give me a weird result. How can I get the desired result in Blender?

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107284/is-there-any-way-to-make-edges-corners-become-rounded/107290#107290

Answer (score 4):

Close to this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107284/is-there-any-way-to-make-edges-corners-become-rounded/107290#107290)

If you extrude your base shape and select the edges corresponding to the vertices you want to round, then you can bevel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> the shape:

[image]